# Full Paths from WYGWAM?

Tags: wygwam

EE 2.7.3c / WYGWAM 3.3.2 / MSM / Native EE File Management

All images/files are loaded on one domain but need to be used on both. WYGWAM is returning relative paths so the client has to manually insert the correct domain.

Is there a way to get WYGWAM to return a full path?

Answer (score 1):

CKEditor has a "config.baseHref" parameter - check http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html
Maybe use the wygwam_config hook ( https://docs.pixelandtonic.com/wygwam/developers/wygwam_config.html ) to set that parameter per site?

Comment: Thanks! I'll give that a try. It doesn't have to be per-site - we're just loading images from one site on the other.

Answer (score 1):

Missed the easy answer - I had relative paths configured on the file upload directories. Changed to full paths there and it comes through in WYGWAM.